# Flutter String formatter

Tags: flutter, dart

how to check if strings is voucher

4 letters separated by (-) then 4 letters separated by (-) then 4 letters separated by (-) 4 letters separated by (-)

ex: ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for that, something like this:

```
void main() {
  String voucher = 'ABCD-ABCD-ABCD-ABCD';
  RegExp voucherRegex = RegExp(r'^[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}$');

  if (voucherRegex.hasMatch(voucher)) {
    print('The string is a voucher');
  } else {
    print('The string is not a voucher');
  }
}
```

this regular expression is only for upper case letters, don't know if can be lower case in your use case